# Terraform issue with using dynamic block for ingress rules on security group

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I am basically trying to create a rule to allow ssh, rdp and http traffic from ip address x.x.x.x/32 (where x.x.x.x is a real ip address).

this is my tf file

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_internet" {
name        = "allow_internet"
description = "allow_internet_from_my_connection"
vpc_id      = aws_vpc.dee_vpc.id

dynamic "ingress" {
for_each = var.sg_protocols
iterator = protocol
content {
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = protocol.value
  cidr_blocks = ["x.x.x.x/32"]
}
```

}

And this is my variable

```
  variable "sg_protocols" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "list of ingress ports"
  default     = ["rdp", "ssh", "rdp"]
  }
```

I get the below error

```
λ terraform plan
Error: Invalid number literal
on securitygroup.tf line 14, in resource "aws_security_group" "allow_internet":
14:       cidr_blocks = [x.x.x.x/32]
Failed to recognize the value of this number literal.
```

Comment: correction 

  default     = ["rdp", "ssh", "http"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the wrong usage of:

- to_port
- from_port
- protocol

You can refer to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group for specific usage.

If you want to use dynamic blocks, you will need to create a more complex object to hold the value of the 3 parameters mentioned above.

And the syntax of the dynamic block is also incorrect.

Try this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_internet" {
  name        = "allow_internet"
  description = "allow_internet_from_my_connection"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.sg_protocols
    content {
      from_port = ingress.value["from_port"]
      to_port = ingress.value["to_port"]
      protocol = ingress.value["protocol"]
      cidr_blocks = ["10.10.10.10/32"]  
    }
  }
}

variable "sg_protocols" {
  type = list(object({
    from_port = number
    to_port = number
    protocol = string
  }))

  default = [
    {
      from_port = 80
      to_port = 80
      protocol = "tcp"
    },
    {
      from_port = 22
      to_port = 22
      protocol = "tcp"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nyxx88 , that makes more sense to me now

Comment: Or you can just use `type = any` (instead of defining the object)